# Deployed Shiny app not showing any UI elements

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I had a fully functional Shiny App (both locally and on Shiny.io). Recently, I made a very small change to the ui: all I did was change the order of one of the panels, a purely cosmetic change.

Afterwards, I published the updated app and all hell broke lose. The deployed app does not have any of the UI elements such as the tabs and sidebar. Not wanting to spend too much time debugging, I pulled up the original working script and tried to publish the old (previously working version), and still, everything is broken. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/clVbZ.jpg... local version on right, deployed on left.

What could have been the problem? Thanks!

Comment: is it possible you are missing a comma between your re-arranged UI elements? hard to say without any app code...

Comment: But the thing is I tried to republish my original (previously working) app from an old script file and received the same error.

The only possible explanation might be the computer. I think my original app was uploaded with my Mac, and I'm currently on a different PC.

Comment: do you still have the script file? perhaps share on github, codepen, maybe even here on SO if it's not super long